# Is there any way to make runes stick when switching skills?

Tags: diablo-iii

When switching skills on my Demon Hunter, for example my primary skill, if the skill has a rune selected and I switch to another skill and then back again the rune will no longer be selected.

Is there a way to lock runes to a skill until manually changed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope. There isn't any way to do this.

That said, if you are just 'browsing' alternative skills and would like to go back to the skill/rune combo you were using before, if you close the skill selection UI using the '**Cancel**' button, your selected skills will not be changed and will retain your old rune selection.

Comment: Thank you, I am mostly just browsing so the cancel button will work just fine for me :)